# Fetch records with DISTINCT and rownum

Tags: sql, performance

I was facing a performance issue while executing following query.Takes too much time to fetch the results.It was fetching whole results(say 3000)at a time.I was trying to fetch 10 records by using `rownum <11`. But it is showing only 3-4 records.Duplicate `header_ids` are present.Can we use DISTINCT and rownum here to get 10 rows. Is there any other way to solve this issue??

```
SELECT DISTINCT oh.header_id,
oh.cust_po_number purchase_order,
oh.order_number,
DECODE(oh.orig_sys_document_ref, NULL, oh.orig_sys_document_ref, SUBSTR(oh.orig_sys_document_ref, LENGTH('OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL')+1)) web_reference_number,
TO_CHAR(oh.ordered_date, 'FMMon-DD-YYYY') date_ordered,
(SELECT MIN(schedule_ship_date)
FROM oe_order_lines_all
WHERE header_id = oh.header_id
And Oh.Sold_To_Org_Id = 12338
) oldest_schedule_ship_date,
oe_totals_grp.get_order_total(ol.header_id,NULL,'ALL') total_value,
oh.transactional_curr_code currency_code,
COUNT(*) over() AS total_count
FROM oe_order_headers_all oh,
oe_order_lines_all ol
Where Oh.Header_Id = Ol.Header_Id
-- AND ol.actual_shipment_date BETWEEN sysdate - 180 AND sysdate
AND oh.sold_to_org_id = 12338
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `rownum`, then I presume you are using Oracle.

Oracle does the `distinct` *after* applying `rownum` rather than before.  Alas.  I think this is part of the same logic where `order by` is applied afterwards as well.

You can fix it by using a subquery:

```
select s.*
from (<your query here>) s
where rownum < 11;
```

Part of your performance problem may be due to the subquery in the `select`.  I think you can replace it with an analytic function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT oh.header_id,
      oh.cust_po_number purchase_order, oh.order_number,
      DECODE(oh.orig_sys_document_ref, NULL, oh.orig_sys_document_ref,
      SUBSTR(oh.orig_sys_document_ref, LENGTH('OE_ORDER_HEADERS_ALL')+1)) web_reference_number,
      TO_CHAR(oh.ordered_date, 'FMMon-DD-YYYY') date_ordered,
      min(schedule_ship_date) over (partition by oh.header_id) as oldest_schedule_ship_date,
      oe_totals_grp.get_order_total(ol.header_id,NULL,'ALL') total_value,
      oh.transactional_curr_code currency_code,
      COUNT(*) over() AS total_count
FROM oe_order_headers_all oh join
     oe_order_lines_all ol
     on Oh.Header_Id = Ol.Header_Id
```

-- AND ol.actual_shipment_date BETWEEN sysdate - 180 AND sysdate
    where oh.sold_to_org_id = 12338

Actually, to me, it looks like the whole query should be written using `group by` rather than `distinct` with analytic functions.  That might help the performance as well.

Comment: yes the rownum is an intern number of the resultrow which is filtered as part of the where clause. so it happens before the distinct.